# Remove drop down entries based on previous selection

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've looked through stackoverflow for an answer and am almost there but need some help.

I have multiple drop down lists with the same options in them. For example three identical lists with the following:

```
<label for='distlist_1'>Distribution List 1</label> 
<select name='distlist_1'> 
<option value=''>Please Select:</option> 
<option value='1'>All</option> 
<option value='2'>All Managers</option>
<option value='3'>Leavers</option>
</select>
```

The only difference being the name eg, distlist_1, 2, 3 etc. I can add ids if necessary.

When a user selects an option in the first drop down list I need it to be removed from all other drops downs. I found a script that did this.

```
$('option').click(function(){
$('option:contains(' + $(this).html() +')').not(this).remove();
});
```

But I need it so that if the user then decides, 'wait I don't need that option in drop down list 1 after all', she picks something else and the option reappears in the other drop downs. The code above removes the options then there is no way of retrieving them until if you click enough they all disappear.

Comment: you can hide the options and then show them again.

Comment: How do I do that, I am stuck? I found this, which works but it is a lot of code - http://forums.asp.net/t/1738132.aspx/1 and I would need to edit it for each set of drop down lists. Was hoping for a concise jquery script. The one in my original script probably just needs tweaking but Im not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this as it was concise...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var selects = $('.mapping')

selects.change(function() {
var vals = {};
selects.each(function() {
vals[this.value] = true;
}).get();
selects.not(this).children().not(':selected').not(':first-child').each(function() {
this.disabled = vals[this.value];
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually does what you want... This is based on jquery 1.7 and the on() event binder

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $('select').on('focus', function() {
        // on focus save the current selected element so you 
        // can place it back with all the other dropdowns
        var current_value = $(this).val();

        // bind the change event, with removes and adds elements
        // to the dropdown lists
        $(this).one('change.tmp', { v : current_value }, function(e)
        {
          if ($(this).val() != '')
          { // do not remove the Please select options
            $('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
              .not($('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]', $(this)))
              .remove();
          }

          if (e.data.v != '')
          { // do not add the Please select options
            $('select').not($(this)).append($('option[value="' + e.data.v + '"]', $(this)).clone());
          }
        });

        // on blur remove all the eventhandlers again, this is needed
        // else you don't know what the previously selected item was.
        $(this).on('blur.tmp', { v : current_value}, function (e)
        {
          $(this).off('blur.tmp');
          $(this).off('change.tmp');
        });
      });
    });
```

The only thing it doesn't do is ordering everything in the right order. You will have to think of your own way of doing that at the .append function.

Comment: That works, brilliant! I have seen so many variations but that works by just dropping it in to the page. Any chance you could also help me implement that where I may have separate bunches of drop downs? IE, my first post, Im ight have printers1, pnrinters2, etc but then later on in the same form/page I may have monitor1, monitor2. As when I run this at the moment if I chnage a drop-down it effects every element on the page.

Comment: Can I use an id for each set of drop downs then implement that at the top of the function somehow?

Comment: Richard, sorry for the late reply ;) anyways, you can easily change this to support for groups... I would suggest that you would use the jquery selector and change it a bit... group them using a certain tag, i would suggest span and give that span an id... then change the selector $('select') to something like this $('select', $('#spanIdHere')) then you only select the select options in the specified element with the Id spanIdHere... cheers ;)

Comment: I ended up using this one as it was shorter and I was easily able to apply it to different groups of selects.